# Как использовать/подключить самописный babel-плагин?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babel

Я написал babel-плагин, который всем переменным с именем **test** присваивает число **777**.

```js
const babel = require('@babel/core');
const code = `const test = 'text'`;

const output = babel.transformSync(code, {
  plugins: [
    function myCustomPlugin() {
      return {
        visitor: {
          Identifier(path) {
            if (path.isIdentifier({ name: 'test' })) {
              path.parentPath.get('init').node.value = 777
            }
          },
        },
      };
    },
  ],
});
```

Сейчас в качестве кода используется строка **code**.

Как мне подключить этот babel-плагин в вэбпаке, чтобы вместо строки **code** был код определённого файла, например *script.js*? Чтобы этот плагин нацелился на определённый файл